# Integrating spring security with struts2 application

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to implement spring security in my struts2 application. I want to apply it to only few endpoints(eg:/login). I want to implement spring security so that the certain endpoints are secured by spring security.

This is a part of my web.xml

```
<!-- Trying to add Spring security -->
   <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:applicationContextSecurity.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

This is my applicationContextSecurity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-5.7.xsd">
<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/manager" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>
<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider>
<user-service>
<user name="test" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
</user-service>
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class = "true" />
</beans:beans>
```

This runs fine but i get a 500 internal server when i run localhost:8080/manager.

```
org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String "//"
    org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.rejectedBlocklistedUrls(StrictHttpFirewall.java:542)
    org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(StrictHttpFirewall.java:505)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:206)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
```

I want to know what changes should i make so that this runs.